# what is means of WCAG 1.1 : The <area> tag is missing a text equivalent

Tags: html

when i use area map in my html page the i got this error

```
<map name="Map" id="Map"><area shape="rect" coords="39,244,134,267" href="#" /></map>
```

are anyone tell me what is wrong in this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `alt` attribute of area is [required](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_area.asp) (or direct from the [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/objects.html#h-13.6.1), if you prefer)